# Powershell Email body formatting not showing as expected

Tags: powershell

The code gathers ping and traceroute info and send it in an email. The output of ping result comes out fine in the email's body but tracert info is not formatted correctly. Please see the example below as seen in the email body. The information must be passed on from variable to the body of email as its done below and not attached as a logfile.

[image: Output seen in the Body of the email]

The code is as below:

```
$TimeSpan = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 1
$EndTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes($TimeSpan.TotalMinutes).ToString("HH:mm")
# $log_file='c:\timee.log'

cls

do
{

write-host 'Gathering logs..wait 2 mins'
$1+=ping google.com |Select-String "Reply"| foreach $_ { $a = Get-Date; 
$a.ToString() + " " + $_ } #| 
Out-File -Append -Encoding UTF8 -FilePath  $log_file
$2+= tracert google.com 
}
until ($EndTime -eq (Get-Date -Format HH:mm))  

$EmailFrom = "from@gmail.com"
$EmailTo = "to@hotmail.com"
$Subject = "Notification from yy"
$Body = $1+$2 
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object 
System.Net.NetworkCredential("from@gmail.com", 
"passwd");
$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)

#Clear-Variable -name '1'


Write-Host "All done" -ForegroundColor Green
```

Comment: Maybe `$body = ($1|Out-String) + ($2|Out-String)`?

Comment: THAT WORKED!! Wooooo!!!!!